# How to compare values and display the message?

Tags: javascript

I have written a function which perform dice roll functionality.I have given the code below ..but the problem is somewhere in the program i want to compare the two value and want to display the message.But why its not happening m not getting?

```
function diceroll(){
            var side1 = document.getElementById("side1");
            var side2 = document.getElementById("side2");
            var status = document.getElementById("status");
            var value1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+ 1);
            var value2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+ 1);
            var totalvalue = value1 + value2;
            side1.innerHTML = value1;
            side2.innerHTML = value2;
            status.innerHTML ="Dice rolled"+totalvalue+".";
```

here below m comparaing the two value and want to show the message that double has appeared on both the sides

```
if(value1 == value2);
  {
    status.innerHTML += "<br/>Got double u can try one more";
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you experience? And either you need to describe the error of this function or show us the whole program when you say that "the problem is *somewhere* in the program".

Comment: thnx  Bergi but i got the answer. Dmitry Volokh made it correct

Comment: If that's the answer, you did a very poor question. The code does something entirely different.

Comment: actually i was comparing value1 and value2 ,whn these values are equal a message should be displayed like "Got double u can try one more time " but it was showing everytime even evrything was perfect...

Comment: Thanks for the problem description, the answer is easy now.

Comment: hey bergi m doing programming first time in my life and  feeling
difficulty in apply logic and think about problem ..any advice can u give me please m realy disappointed with myself?

Comment: You're logic was fine, it's only some kind of syntax error. But if you ask for advice, you need to be very specific about what you want it to do and what unexpected thing it does

Comment: Thx Bergi !! here it is ok but i get stuck when i have to think on some problem is it normal for beginner or i wont b able to learnin programmin?

Answer (score 1):

```
function diceroll(){
            var side1 = document.getElementById("side1");
            var side2 = document.getElementById("side2");
            var status = document.getElementById("status");
            var value1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+ 1);
            var value2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+ 1);
            var totalvalue = value1 + value2;
            side1.innerHTML = value1;
            side2.innerHTML = value2;
            status.innerHTML = value1 === value2 ? "Got double u can try one more" :"Dice rolled"+totalvalue+".";
}
```

Comment: thnx a lot @Dmitry Volokh ..actly m new to js programming

Answer (score 0):

use === equal to solve. Which compare both value as well as type of var. Thanks @neo, i removed one =.

Comment: that's too many `=`. Even for javascript :-)

Comment: thnx hariharan but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You've got a problem here:

```
if(value1 == value2);
//                  ^
  {
    status.innerHTML += "<br/>Got double u can try one more";
  }
```

The semicolon denotes an empty statement, which is guarded by the if-condition. The block below will always execute, it doesn't belong to the `if` - it is executed as

```
if (value1 == value2) {
    /*nothing*/;
}
{
    status.innerHTML += "<br/>Got double u can try one more";
}
```

Remove the semicolon and your code will work:

```
if (value1 == value2) {
    status.innerHTML += "<br/>Got double u can try one more";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function twoNum()
    {
            var side1 = document.getElementById('txtFirstNumber');
            var side2 = document.getElementById('txtSecondNumber');
            var status = document.getElementById('status');
            var value1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+ 1);
            var value2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+ 1);
            var totalvalue = value1 + value2;
            side1.innerHTML = value1;
            side2.innerHTML = value2;
            alert(value1);
            alert(value2);
            status.innerHTML = value1 === value2 ? "Got double u can try one more" :"Dice rolled"+totalvalue+".";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    First Number :<input id="txtFirstNumber" type="text" /><br />
    Second Number:<input id="txtSecondNumber" type="text" />
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="twoNum();" />
   <div id="status"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```